# How can I select a specific ID to do something?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently working on a project, now I'm facing a problem where I want to select specific IDs to do something.

How can I select specific IDs to get an img so a wall can be created?

As you can see, every tile has its own unique tile id, now I want to select all the ids from *tile0-0 to tile 0-12* and create an img for those unique ids.

How can I do that?

The code that creates those tiles:

```html
function DrawMap()
{
  var X = Map.length;
  var Y = Map[0].length;

  var Output = "";
  for(var x = 0; x < X; x++)
  {
    for(var y = 0; y < Y; y++)
    {
      var _x = ((x*32)+(y*-32)+OffsetX);
      var _y = ((x*16)+(y*16)+OffsetY);

      if(Map[x][y])
        Output += '<img id="tile'+x+'-'+y+'" class="square" style="top: ' + _y + 'px; left: ' + _x + 'px;" src="/web/img/rooms/on.png" alt="Click To Remove" />';
      else
        Output += '<img id="tile'+x+'-'+y+'" class="square" style="top: ' + _y + 'px; left: ' + _x + 'px;" src="/web/img/rooms/off.png" alt="Click To Add" />';
    }
```

Comment: Post a snippet instead of a screen shot :)

Comment: Oh haha changing that now! Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

You can select all elements with this code:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^="tile0-"]');
```

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('[id^="tile0-"]').style.backgroundImage = "url('img_tree.png')"; Like this to add an image to all the specific ids? Where can I place this code?

Comment: The code above returns an array, each element of which can be assigned an image by iterating through it.

Comment: Im a beginner i'm sorry, i did this: https://imgur.com/TxMkYUR

Comment: `let elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="tile0-"]');
elements.forEach(el => el.style.backgroundImage = "url('img_tree.png')")`

Comment: I really appreciate your help thank you! I tried it again and it didn't work. https://imgur.com/BSU07eM